# Is is better to have multiple smaller or one big polygon

Tags: textures, performance

My game has some kind of minecraft (voxel) graphic and I have the opportunity to decide whether I want to render multiple smaller polygons or one big polygon.

Which is better for performance?

Comment: Did you hit a performance bottleneck while drawing your polygon?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt No I was just thinking that it would be better to use one big polygon to not have shadow artifacts between the polygon borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Smaller" and "bigger" are relative terms, of course.

That said, tessellating your surfaces (i.e. breaking them into smaller triangles) will usually help up to a point, and then it'll hurt.

Large triangles suffer from a number of problems. For one, any per-vertex shader calculations will result in more obvious artifacts along the edges between triangles of planar surfaces. You mentioned in a comment a problem with shadow artifacts; bigger triangles will reduce the number of areas with artifacts but will increase their severity where they do exist. Smaller triangles should reduce the artifacts' severity or even eliminate them entirely, assuming nothing else is wrong with your shadowing algorithm.

Small triangles also have problems. Mainly, they entail more vertices being transferred to the GPU and more invocations of the vertex shader than larger triangles would.

There's other considerations at play, too. If you duplicate all shared vertices on a continuous surface, you'll (probably) get much worse performance than if you use an index buffer and share the vertices. The difference is how many vertex shader invocations are required and how big your vertex buffers must be. Cubes should be hard to do poorly, but it's certainly possible.

If you want a for-sure answer, you have to actually *measure performance* for your particular game on your target hardware. For a general case, though, tessellate your cube surfaces into fourths or sixteenths.

Note that when I say "tessellate" I mean it in the general geometric sense, not necessarily tessellation shaders. Whether or not you want to use tessellation shaders to automatically sub-divide your cube surfaces is a bigger topic, and not one I'm qualified to answer (I have no experience with them).